# Changes not reflected on my github after deploying in heroku

Tags: django, python-2.7, heroku, github, deployment

I have deployed  a demo app given by [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#view-logs) and pushed all changes to my github according to Heroku by Heroku create command-

```
heroku create
Creating lit-bastion-5032 in organization heroku... done, stack is cedar-14
http://lit-bastion-5032.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/lit-bastion-5032.git
Git remote heroku added
```

> My terminal

[image]

But changes not reflected to my github account for same email_id. plz help

Comment: `heroku create` will not automatically add a remote repository for your Github account. You should manually add it.

Comment: But the files are pushed to somewhere by heroku create command

Comment: When you do a `git push heroku master` (or equivalent) you are only pushing your local changes to your heroku account to be deployed.

Comment: Ok then first i have to create a repository in github

Comment: @RahulSatal, yes, and also explicitly push your code to it. You'll have two remotes: one for GitHub and one for Heroku. Pushing to one doesn't affect the other (unless you automate this yourself).